Non-free memory in bpy.types.Panel. Solved
I ran into a problem when creating a class instance inside the draw function at the panel. The fact is that when restarting addons in my addon, the values that were involved in the instance of the class are reset to default and an error appears when closing the blender:
Not freed memory blocks: 144, total unfreed memory 0.010300 MB

apparently, this is connected with the instance of the class. In principle, I can do without it, but my ui code becomes just incredibly cumbersome and unreadable
here is code of draw function:
class UIMode:
    def __init__(self, collection, props_override, do_override, do_override_name, prop, prop_index, listname, list_prop, list_prop_index, name):
        self.collection = collection
        self.props_override = props_override
        self.do_override = do_override
        self.do_override_name = do_override_name
        self.prop = prop
        self.prop_index = prop_index
        self.listname = listname
        self.list_prop = list_prop
        self.list_prop_index = list_prop_index
        self.name = name


def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        settings = scene.global_settings

        row = layout.row(align=True)
        row.prop(settings, 'enum_settings_mode', expand=True)
        
        layout.use_property_split = True
        layout.use_property_decorate = False

        def scatter(props):...

        def passive(props):...

        def active(props):...

        ui_selector = {
            'SCATTER': scatter,
            'PASSIVE': passive,
            'ACTIVE': active,}


        ui_classifier = {
            'SCATTER': self.UIMode(scene.s_collection,scene.s_override, settings.override_scatter, 'override_scatter', scene.s_objects, scene.s_objects_index, "POB_UL_ScatterObjects", 's_objects', 's_objects_index', 'Scatter'),
            'PASSIVE': self.UIMode(scene.p_collection, scene.p_override, settings.override_passive, 'override_passive', scene.p_objects, scene.p_objects_index, "POB_UL_PassiveObjects", 'p_objects', 'p_objects_index', 'Passive'),
            'ACTIVE': self.UIMode(scene.a_collection, scene.a_override, settings.override_active, 'override_active', scene.a_objects, scene.p_objects_index, "POB_UL_ActiveObjects", 'a_objects', 'a_objects_index', 'Active')
        }

        def ui(mode):
            ui_mode = ui_classifier[mode]

            if ui_mode.name == 'Active' and settings.enum_pipeline == 'COMPLEX':
                row = layout.row()
                row.label(text="Only in advanced mode", icon='INFO')

            elif ui_mode.collection is None:
                row = layout.row()
                row.label(text= f"{ui_mode.collection} collection is not specified or empty", icon='INFO')

            elif len(ui_mode.collection.objects) < 1:
                row = layout.row()
                row.label(text= f"{ui_mode.collection} collection is empty", icon='INFO')
            
            elif settings.enum_pipeline == "SIMPLE":
                props = ui_mode.props_override
                ui_selector.get(mode)(props)

            elif settings.enum_pipeline == "COMPLEX":
                row = layout.row()
                row.template_list(ui_mode.listname, "", scene, ui_mode.list_prop, scene, ui_mode.list_prop_index)    
                row = layout.row()
                row.prop(settings, ui_mode.do_override_name , text="Override")

                if ui_mode.do_override:
                    props = ui_mode.props_override
                else:
                    props = ui_mode.prop[ui_mode.prop_index]

                ui_selector.get(mode)(props)
        
        ui(settings.enum_settings_mode)


panel code example
class MyPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
        bl_idname = "MyPanel"
        bl_label = "MyPanel"
        bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}

        def draw(self, context):
            layout = self.layout
            scene = context.scene

            class UIMode:
                def __init__(self, collection):
                    self.collection = collection

            # Create the UIMode instance if it doesn't exist
            if not ui_mode:
                ui_mode = UIMode(my_collection)

SOLUTION: After 12 hours of searching problem and code refactoring, I realized that the problem was in the depsgraph handler function, I did not add the list update condition, and the properties just depend on the list. That is, I deleted and added objects every time any property changed...
(however, this did not solve the memory problem, the error always looks the same, I do not know what it is)

Are you able to reproduce it consistently? Can you provide some sample code that can consistently reproduce this problem?

As a rule of thumb draw should only be used to display data, not to modify data, be it Blender data or plain old python data.

@HarryMcKenzie yes

I’m glad you found a solution, but please don’t edit it into the original question: Post it properly as an answer instead.
